# Retrieve time-stamp of HTTP file using WinHttp function

Tags: c++, http, winapi, winhttp

How to get the time stamp of a file, that can be downloaded from HTTP server, using HTTP protocol? I am particularly interested in [WinHttp functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384257(v=vs.85).aspx), but any HTTP reference will do.

There is a time-stamp field in response-header, but that refers the time when the HTTP server *responded*, and not the file-time of the file.

Comment: Is the `Last-Modified` header what you need?

Comment: Yes, probably. My further search revealed that. Finding how exactly it would work, and to ensure given web-server supports this in reply to HEADer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the creation/modified date-time of a file received over HTTP, there exists a field `Last-Modified` within the HTTP response header.

As the documentation says:

> The Last-Modified entity-header field indicates the date and time at
>   which the origin server believes the variant was last modified [...]
>   The exact meaning of this header field depends on the implementation
>   of the origin server and the nature of the original resource. For
>   files, it may be just the file system last-modified time

WinHttp function to retrieve the header info is  [WinHttpQueryHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102(v=vs.85).aspx).